# Summer REU question

Tags: soft-question, research-practice

I am an undergraduate trying to decide between two specific REU's for this summer. 
One is the SMALL Williams College REU, and the other is CalTech's SURF program. Leaving aside the specific topics I'd be working on for each (one is in computational origami, the other 
in complexity theory - and I am interested in both), does anyone have any experience with either they could share? 
I am interested in working atmosphere (group in SMALL or individual in CalTech), how much actual results were produced/published in each, how helpful each it was for preparing you for graduate school (if you are attending one already), etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not have experience with a REU at Williams. I am, however, familiar with their department (which is absolutely fantastic). The department specifically does not do graduate students so that they can pour every resource into giving their undergrads a graduate level education. Students are required to give at least one math talk on advanced topics and answer questions from all faculty, they have regular math dinners and events and the university, being small, is close knit and fosters collaboration. Professor Adams is a true expert on knot theory (you might work with him...)

Comment: Take what I say as an uninformed, biased, partial piece of advice from a stranger. I do not know what CalTech's SURF program will offer you. What I do want to say is that what experience I have at the math department at Williams impressed me. Take this in the context that the math department at my school (Rochester Institute of Technology) does not offer introductory courses on advanced topics; only advanced courses on introductory topics.

Comment: @Ross make this an answer ?

Comment: This has been around a while and I'm no longer sure this is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

SMALL is one of the most competitive math REUs in the country.  By contrast, it's very easy to get a SURF.  If I were to choose one it would be SMALL because you could probably apply to SURF next year and easily get accepted.